# Using join method in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

i have this nested array arr:

[[ "one", "two" , "three"]]
I want to extract the values and join them in a var called numbers and separate them by ";"

I used this method :

```
var itemsArray = arr.join(";");
```

what i a getting is this :

```
one,two,three
```

Although what i am aiming for is one;two;three

It's reading the separator.

Comment: Use `arr[0].join(';');`. The array is nested array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a **nested array**, with the array being in the zeroth index, but you are joining the parent array. Use:

```
arr[0].join(';');
```

This takes the first index of the array and joins it.

```js
var arr = [
  ["one", "two", "three"]
];
console.log(arr[0].join(';'));
```

Answer (score 3):

if the array is nested and number of levels are only two, then try

```js
var arr = [[ "one", "two" , "three"]];
var itemsArray = arr.map( function( item ){ return item.join( ";" )  } ).join(";");

console.log( itemsArray );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a deep joining for nested arrays.

```js
var array = ['zero', ['one', 'two' , 'three', ['four', ['five', 'six', ['seven'], 'eight']]]],
    string = array.map(function join(a) { 
        return Array.isArray(a) ? a.map(join).join(';') : a;
    }).join(";");

console.log(string);
```